# Nginx: How can I redirect old content to the homepage?

Tags: nginx, redirect

All my old content (which no longer exists) is in the path mysite.com/2007/*

How can I write a redirect in nginx to redirect any requests to 2007 back to the homepage?

At the moment they just display a 404.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide your config, but basically you need to insert this line into your "location" config:

```
rewrite "^/2007/.+$" / break;
```

Comment: You should not, though, that this creates two URIs for your content, whereas if you use the permanent flag instead of break then you get a 301 redirect.

Comment: You're right, this would be better:
rewrite "^/2007/.+$" / permanent;